# laravel app cannot detect https schema behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've a following config:

```
<client> <ssl nginx> <80 nginx> <laravel>
```

laravel has a method called `asset()` which is supposed to detect schema and output correct url. But it doesn't, I asked question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722331/laravel-asset-method-doesnt-return-https) - but its clear it is not php issue, but something with server.

My hunch is that `<ssl nginx>` is not passing some vital information to `<80 nginx>`.

Can I add something to `<80 nginx>` virtualhost config so that it thinks request came from `https`? (client came from https, but laravel doesn't see this it sees only `<80 nginx>`).

I tried to add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https` to virtualhost config, but it didn't change anything.

<80 nginx> config:
[image]

Comment: How many different copies of nginx are you running?!? And where is the configuration? This question really isn't answerable as is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton 2 copies of nginx, one is https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy as a front, and on back I've stock nginx container.